# I18n for flash messages with parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, notifications, notice, rails-i18n

How can I add parameters to my parametrized and internationalized error message? Say, in my controller there's:

```
flash[:error] = t(:error)[:my_error_message]
```

And in en.yml:

```
error:
  my_error_message: "This is the problem XXX already."
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your flash message,

```
flash[:error] = t('my_error_message', :problem => 'Big Problem')
```

In your en.yml:

```
error:
  my_error_message: "This is the problem %{problem} already."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t('error.my_error_message')
```

or:

```
t(:my_error_message, scope: :error)
```